# Display Manager isn't starting on fresh Debian 10 install

Tags: debian, desktop-environment, startx, sddm

I just installed Debian 10 (amd64) on my desktop.  During the install GUI I told it to install both the Gnome and KDE desktop environments, and when it asked me which desktop manager I wanted to use (between gdm3 and sddm) I selected SDDM.

However on boot, it doesn't load the DM graphical login, I land instead at a terminal login.  I can log in and then type startx, and the Gnome DE loads just fine, however whatever happened to SDDM and starting up X on boot?  You would assume this should be configured by the installer since I selected it?  I'm assuming I've either got a dud install or this is just one of those "oh you have to edit this file manually" kind of things haha.

If anyone can please help me, that'd would be hugely appreciated.  Thanks.

Installed Debian version:
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:    10
Codename:   buster

Comment: What's your systemd default target?

Comment: Sorry how do I find that out?  I tried googling but couldn't find anything for systemd that referred to a "default target"

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-systemctl-to-manage-systemd-services-and-units, see the part about runlevel

Comment: Thanks for that, allows me to understand the workings of debian so much better.  My default target is graphical.target.  I assume this means it's meant to launch x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I've solve this now rather unexpectedly.  I got fed up trying to find a solution and moved on to installing my graphics chipset drivers, and then suddenly booting into graphical mode started working.  It seems odd that graphics drivers were required to reach the required target state, but at least now I understand the cause.